# ¿Como crear una mascara dependiendo de la longitud de un input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tengo esta librería

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Mi HTML

```
<input type="text" name="" class="form-input" id="precio" maxlength="15">
```

JS.
Puse mi mascara asi:

```
$('#precio').mask('$000,000.00');
```

Me funciona bien pero que pasa si yo escribo 1000 tendria que cambiar mi mascara a `$('#precio').mask('$0,000.00');`
Para que tome ese formato, y lo que quiero es que dependiendo si escribo 25000 me de el formato que quiero, algun consejo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se usa una librería es recomendable leerse la documentación que esta nos facilita. Revisando esta, vi que uno de los ejemplos era para representar valores monetarios. Lo único que le faltaba era que no añadía el símbolo del dolar al principio de la máscara.

Como no vi alguna solución en la documentación y tras hacer unas pruebas al final programé una pequeña funcionalidad adicional para cubrir esta carencia.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#precio').mask('#,##0.00', {reverse: true});
  
  $('#precio').change(function () {
    var valor = $(this).val();  
    $(this).val('$' + valor);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="" class="form-input" id="precio" maxlength="15">
```

**Referencia:** [Jquery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html)

Comment: Gracias amigo, era lo que buscaba